# translate and scale images continously

Tags: css, reactjs

I am currently working on reactjs. I want to this type of animation in css for my site. I have placed a reference of site where this animation is done [Open this site in pc or desktop mode](https://playplay.com/)
Anyone who can help please guide me here. Animation is just below the navbar on home page

Comment: In cases you didn't know, you may have a look at these React libraries before someone provides an answer. [react-spring](https://www.react-spring.io/), [Framer Motion](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/examples/) I haven't used these libraries extensively but they seem to be promising.

Comment: oh ok Thanks. @Hangindev